# UIScrollView+UIView instead of UITableView+customcells?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I need `UIView` created automatically when scrolling happens. One `UIView` disappear and one `UIView` appear. Invisible `UIView` should be unloaded from memory like than I use `UITableView` and loaded back than I scroll back. Is it possible?

Comment: If you have the necessary programming skills almost everything is possible.

Comment: Have a look at the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol. `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` would be a good starting point...

Comment: Did you mean, scrollview recycling? like in tableView?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely possible, you can just reference the UITableView,including its datasource and delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my example of RecyclingScrollView

https://github.com/iSevenDays/RecyclingScrollView/tree/new